# activeadmin, has_many, and ckeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, activeadmin

I'm putting up the same question I asked here in activeadmin's issues board on github:
https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/645

Hi,

I have two different issues.

1: i love the way active admin handles has_many relationships with a simple DSL like so:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Artist do
   form do |f| 
     f.inputs do
       f.input :name
       f.input :description 
     end
     f.inputs "ArtistLinks" do
       f.has_many :artist_links do |j| 
         j.inputs :title, :url
       end 
     end 

     f.buttons
   end 
 end
```

The ability to add more links at the bottom of the form is great.

However,I have been using a wyiswyg which i can't seem to get working in this format. I've been using/adding it with a partial like so:

```
  ActiveAdmin.register NewsItem do
    form :partial => "/news_items/form"
  end
```

## /app/views/news_item/_form.html.erb

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" %>
 <%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @news_item], :multipart => true do |f| %>
 <%= f.inputs :title, :photo, :excerpt %>
 <%= cktext_area_tag("news_item[content]", @news_item.content) %>
 <%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

However, 
in my partial, i can't seem to be able to make the has_many relationship nicely like so:

```
 f.inputs "ArtistLinks" do
   f.has_many :artist_links do |j| 
     j.inputs :title, :url
   end 
 end
```

Could you either explain to me how to get my wysiwyg which uses a form helper cktext_area_tag into my admin resource or explain to me how to get that nice has_many into my view partial?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `has_many` does not work in partials is because Active Admin tells you to use `semantic_form_for` when writing your partial. Active Admin extends [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) which it uses to generate forms. It does so by creating its own form builder that extends the Formtastic builder and adds, among others, the `has_many` method. So if you want to use that inside partials you have to use the Active Admin form builder. To do that use `active_admin_form_for` instead of `semantic_form_for`.

If you have problems using `active_admin_form_for`, take a look at [my branch](https://github.com/watson/active_admin/tree/dsl_form_builder) which should fix most of the issues (it's still beta - but I'm working on getting it into Active Admin core)